# Default Value with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user table that I would like to have a default value for all the types except I want the default values to be different for each type. I have a before_create callback method on the base class that has the value set to something and I override that method in the classes that inherit it for the other values, but every time I seed I get a RecordNotSaved error. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code for your before_create callbacks in your classes? I'm betting they're inadvertently returning false, which is a common reason for RecordNotSaved. RecordNotSaved is basically telling you the object isn't valid. Check out the docs for RecordNotSaved, hope that helps.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thanks!

Comment: can I add it as an answer? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your callbacks for before_create; if they're returning false, you'll get this error. RecordNotSaved indicates a validation error, in general, and if your callbacks return false, even inadvertently, you'll get that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a database trigger to set default value, and I would be recommend `before_save` rather than `before_create`. Let's say you are building classes on Cars.

```

```
class Car
  before_save :default_type
  def default_type
    self.car_type ||= self.class.name
  end
end

class Honda < Car
end

class Tesla < Car
end
```

```